# Adwords API ReportDefinitionService: ReportDefinition not found

Tags: php, namespaces, yii2, google-ads-api, classnotfound

If I do :

```
$user->GetService('ManagedCustomerService');
$customer = new \ManagedCustomer();
```

This works, but if I do:

```
$user->LoadService('ReportDefinitionService');
$report = new \ReportDefinition();
```

I receive an error: Class 'ReportDefinition' not found.
(I write on Yii2, use api v201607)

What did I do wrong?

=========== FIX =================

I temporary made it working by adding:

```
require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/vendor/googleads/googleads-php-lib/examples/AdWords/v201607/init.php';
require_once ADWORDS_UTIL_VERSION_PATH . '/ReportUtils.php';
```

Comment: have you added class in namespace ??

ty y adding this use app\Your-Path\ReportDefinition;

Comment: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201603/ReportDefinitionService.ReportDefinitionField

Answer (score 0):

You can't create reports with the `ReportDefinitionService` since API version `v201109`. Use the [ad-hoc reports](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/reporting) instead.

Comment: the problem with namespace ReportDefinition - not with load service. in example folder this code works well.

Comment: My bad—previously (before ad-hoc reports), there was a SOAP type `ReportDefinition` in the WSDL of `ReportDefinitionService`. I thought you were trying to use that type. Disregard my answer.